# Does Yii Cache external javascript files and CSS files?

Tags: caching, yii

Does Yii Cache external javascript files and CSS files?

I want to cache my home page using Yii cache.
The file size of my home page is quite small(excluding js and css). The cached size is 5.7K in my database.

I am wondering whether Yii cache external js and css files?

I do think It does not cache external images files.

Comment: Caching static assets like JS and CSS is mostly the job of your web server, not your PHP framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yii can cache the dynamic content it generates [a couple of different ways](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview) by storing it as static content, including caching [database results](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data), [page fragments](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.fragment), etc. Anything queried from the database and dynamically turned into an HTML document by PHP can be cached by the framework.

*CSS, JS and Images are (usually) already static content, which the framework is not generating, so it cannot cache it.*

Static content is mostly cached in the client's web browser, or on fast distributed content delivery (CDN) servers.

That said, Yii can do a few things to help speed up CSS and JS:

[Yii's CAssetManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626101/whats-the-point-of-yiis-assetmanager) allows you to [use Yii to compress your static scripts](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.performance#minimizing-script-files) (using 3rd party tools) and then "cache" the optimized scripts (in the `assets` folder). This can also be done with server scripts and extensions.

You can also specify different [cache backends](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview#caching), like Memcached and APC, where Yii will store the HTML it caches, but again that does not directly affect your images and CSS/JS.